# Reading from excel Groovy Scripting using jxl api

Tags: excel, groovy, soapui, jxl

```
import jxl.*                                // import library
import jxl.write.*
def fr = new File(“D:\\data1.xls”)
Workbook wk = Workbook.getWorkbook(fr);
def s1 = wk.getSheet(0);
def r = s1.getRows();
for(def i=0;i<r;i++)
{
def c1 = s1.getCell(0, i) 
def c2 = s1.getCell(1, i)
testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Properties"].setPropertyValue  ("num1",c1.getContents())
testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Properties"].setPropertyValue("num2",c2.getContents())
}
```

I am using this code snippet to read data from an excel sheet(xls) and to save it into properties. But on running my test case it is giving error(Multiple Compilation error exception error).

What modifications should I do in my code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922)

Comment: What are the error messages the compiler gives you?

Comment: 1)unexpected char at line 1 and 13 , there are 20-30 error lines . It could be due to jar file also? but I have downloaded it and placed it in lib folder

Comment: i guess bad chars : `“...”` must be `"..."`